# How to show quantisation error for frequency coefficient

Tags: matrices, algorithms, signal-processing

I have the following question from an exam which reads:

[image: quantisation question]

For the second question my answer is:

```
24 5 2 3
 9 2 1 3
 2 3 2 2
 1 1 1 0
```

I am unsure of what formula to apply to each value to get the quantisation error. Can anybody tell me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the data is reconstructed from the quantized coefficients, the resulting coefficients will be

```
240 100  60 120
180  60  40 210
 60 120 140 200
 40  70 100   0
```

Thus the (signed) quantization errors are

```
 -3   2  -3  -3
 -7  -5   8  32
 -8  -1   9   2
-14 -23  38 -81
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you!